# FlexBox Order: Deriving Value from Combining Classes

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

Is it possible to have the flexbox order set by the class (a value from 0-99) added to a data property (a multiple of 100)?

---

I have a large number of `div` elements in a flexbox layout, each of which has the following:

- A class defining what type of card it is. Title, intro, etc
- A data property specifying the theme/subject matter

Right now, the flexbox order is dictated by the type class, such that titles are 1, the intro is 10, etc

This works fine when only one theme is being displayed, but when two or more are displayed then I obviously have all of the titles, then all of the intros, etc.

---

## An Example

```html
<div id="someName" class="typeTitle" data-theme="someTheme">
```

```css
.typeIntroText {order: 10;}
/*not sure of the syntax for data-theme=someTheme*/ {order: 300;}
```

My hope is that the div would have an order of 310.

Comment: I think Its bit confusing,can u please add some snippets or codes or screens explaining your issue.?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.